# Search Google News for articles within a date range

Tags: google-news

How can I search Google News for items and stories that fall within a date range?

For example, I want to search news articles on "hockey" with dates between 2007-2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Google News
2. Click on the drop-down arrow in the right side of the search box
   [image]
3. From the drop-down menu, look for **Date added to Google News:** and choose your convenient option
   [image]
4. Click **Search**